How can I script a driver that randomly selects between multiple variables?
I'd like to create a driver that in essence change the Z position of a large group of objects. Think of heads in a stadium crowd bobbing up and down. In order to make this easy I'd like it all contained in one driver, that unites 5 or so variables which all have their own motion. I'd like the driver to randomly assign one of the 5 variables, so that I am not tasked with assigning the driver to each object individually, but only have to control my 5 variables.

This sounds like a XY Problem. Please explain what you are trying to achieve instead of how, I suspect there are better solutions than drivers. Like Geonodes.
